# What are the disadvantages of utilitarianism?

Tags: utilitarianism

For a philosophy that is founded on usefulness I don't see much of a disadvantage. But, I'd love know more about it.

Comment: This question is too broad for this site, and is better addressed by reading online encyclopedias, e.g. [IEP Utilitarianism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/util-a-r/). We take more specific questions that come up after general reading.

Comment: The problem with utilitarianism is that it's complicated and recursive and requires a lot of knowledge. That's why rules of thumb like the 10 commandments, liberalism or humanism have been developped. We all need heuristics to some degree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia describes utilitarianism as

> Utilitarianism is a family of consequentialist ethical theories that promotes actions that maximize happiness and well-being for the majority of a population.

The article [lists ten criticisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism#Criticisms) of utilitarianism which might be viewed as disadvantages.  Here are two of them.

1. [Does focusing on utility ignore justice?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism#Utility_ignores_justice) That is, would utilitarianism "be prepared to punish an innocent person for the greater good"?

This issue is also raised by G. E. M. Anscombe more generally in *Modern Moral Philosophy*. At the end of her paper she claims that her complaint is that such theories permit one "to procure the judicial condemnation of the innocent".

2. [Can one even predict effectively the consequences for utilitarianism to work?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism#Predicting_consequences)

> Some argue that it is impossible to do the calculation that utilitarianism requires because consequences are inherently unknowable.

---

Anscombe, G. E. M. (1958). Modern moral philosophy. Philosophy, 33(124), 1-19.

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, May 19). Utilitarianism. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 12:33, May 22, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Utilitarianism&oldid=897848977

Comment: Thank you, Frank!